# Unable to secure flow step in Grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm using Grails 2.2.2, Spring WebFlow 2.0.0 and Spring-Security-Core 2.0-RC2 plugins.  I would like to secure the final step in the flow, but have been unable.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/myController/connect?execution=e*s3': ["isFullyAuthenticated()"]
]
```

When a user attempts to go to the final step of the flow, if they are not fully authenticated I would like to redirect them to the login page.  This works fine for other actions in my project, just not the webflows.

I found some documentation suggesting that Spring Web Flows and Spring Security can be used together: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/ch07s04.html.

Any ideas? Is this possiblein Grails?

Answer (score 2):

The querystring is stripped from the url before security checks, so I think you need to do this check yourself explicitly.

The implementation of `isFullyAuthenticated()` in `SecurityExpressionRoot` is

```
public final boolean isFullyAuthenticated() {
    return !trustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && !trustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication);
}
```

so you can dependency-inject the `authenticationTrustResolver` bean and do the same check, e.g.

```
class MyController {
   def authenticationTrustResolver
   def springSecurityService

   def action() {

      if (params.execution == 'e*s3' && !isFullyAuthenticated()) {
         response.sendError 401
         return
      }

      ...
   }

   private boolean isFullyAuthenticated() {
      def authentication = springSecurityService.authentication
      !authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(authentication) && !authenticationTrustResolver.isRememberMe(authentication)
   }
}
```

Comment: So using this approach will I be able to send the user to the login page and then have them redirected back to this step in the flow?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
  '/myController/connect': ["(request.getParameter('execute')?:'').matches('^e.*?s3\$') ? fullyAuthenticated : permitAll"]
]
```

The idea is that the HttpServletRequest is exposed for the expression, so we can decide if fullyAuthenticated is returned or permitAll is returned.

Comment: Cool stuff - SpEL adds a ton of power to Spring Security

Comment: @RobWinch thanks, this adds the security to the flow step but once the user authenticates, it redirects them back to the beginning of the flow. Is there a way to redirect to the current step in the flow?

Answer (score 0):

cant you just import this class and add this annotation with the matchin role for your users to be to your step´s method ?

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class MyClass() {

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def lastStep() {
        // do things
    }

}
```

not authenticated users will be redirected to login page

Comment: Just a note, webflow actions are closures not methods.